# How to run only one job concurrently?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have one hangfire server with ~50 recurring jobs. Hangfire setting up on IIS like in [this example](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html).
Recurring jobs added to hangfire in startup.cs like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(job.desctiprion,
            () => job.startJob(), 
            job.cron, 
            TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

I need to add new recurring job which running every minute. But there is little chance that this job will be running longer minute. My goal - provide to concurrently work only one exemplar of this job.

What solutions are there? As I understand need something like queue with one thread, but queues don't support thread settings.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, 'only one' and 'concurrently' don't really seem to go together.  This: *provide to concurrently work only one exemplar of this job* doesn't make any sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: So you just want to ensure that this job doesn't overlap with itself?

Comment: I need avoid situation when at one moment more than one instance of this recurring job in processing. Yes I just want to ensure that this job doesn't overlap with itself.
For example: first job run in 17:00 and this run take 2 minutes 30 seconds. I need avoid job run in 17:01 and 17:02 but run job in 17:03.

I understand that I can use any flag in the database for verification whether the job is now running . But perhaps in Hangfire has a simple and correct solution to this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `DisableConcurrentExecution` filter to prevent concurrent executions.

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 60)]
public void SomeJob()
{
  //method body
}
```

> This filter places a distributed lock in the beginning of a method
>   performance and releases it after it was completed using the
>   `IServerFilter` interface. The type and method name are being used as a
>   locking resource. Each storage uses its own distributed lock
>   implementation. ([read more here](http://odinserj.net/2014/05/21/hangfire-0.8.2-released/#toc_2))

Comment: Thanks, you answer is very helpfull.
Can also be used  [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)] for avoid large jobs count in retry.

Answer (score -5):

```
 var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
 private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
        // do your task here
 }
 private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

       //Do when completed 
 }
```

Comment: Your answer deviates from what OP is asking. He is using hangfire for background job processing. Using `BackgroundWorked` for this purpose would be a totally different thing.